# Copy object with ebean and get the id of the new object

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am using Play 2.2.3 with Java against a DB2 database.

My goal is to make a copy of an object, save it to the database and then get the id of the new object to use it in a redirect.

The Code looks as follows:

```
Teilnehmer teilnehmer = Teilnehmer.getTeilnehmer(id);
Teilnehmer copy = (Teilnehmer) teilnehmer._ebean_createCopy();
copy.id = null;

copy.save();

Ebean.refresh();

return updateTeilnehmerForm(copy.id);
```

The `copy`-object is fine and exactly how I need it and it is properly saved to the database. The problem is that I cannot call `Ebean.refresh()` because the `copy.id` of the copy-object is still `null` and it is the same for the method call in the return statement.

Error message (from `Ebean.refresh()`):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: The id is null
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.querydefn.DefaultOrmQuery.setId(DefaultOrmQuery.java:1125)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.querydefn.DefaultOrmQuery.setId(DefaultOrmQuery.java:52)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultBeanLoader.refreshBeanInternal(DefaultBeanLoader.java:413)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultBeanLoader.refresh(DefaultBeanLoader.java:356)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.refresh(DefaultServer.java:509)
    at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.refresh(Ebean.java:634)
    at controllers.Application.copyTeilnehmer(Application.java:138)
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$18$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(routes_routing.scala:249)
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$18$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(routes_routing.scala:249)
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$7$$anon$2.invocation(Router.scala:183)
    at play.core.Router$Routes$$anon$1.invocation(Router.scala:377)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:56)
    at play.GlobalSettings$1.call(GlobalSettings.java:64)
    at controllers.BSBTVSecurity$AuthenticatedAction.call(BSBTVSecurity.java:41)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:91)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:90)
    at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82)
    at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:249)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:37)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

I tried using explicit Getters and Setters for the Id but nothing seems to work at that moment. I also tried to get the next id from the database sequence but that only returned `null`. It seems that Ebean is using a generic platform and not the specific DB2Platform which could be an issue.

When I don't dispatch to the `updateTeilnehmerForm` and just reload the overview page where the new database entry should show up, everything is fine and the template seems to be able to read the id.

I hope you guys have an idea because I am at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out. The problem lies within Ebean version 3.2.2 which appearently is included in Play 2.2.3.
After some decompiling I saw that the `DatabasePlatformFactory` had no "case" for a DB2 database. Therefore the generic Platform was used every time.
After some researching on Github I found that this was fixed in later versions. I updated the Ebean dependency to 3.2.5 by adding this line to the `build.sbt` file:

```
dependencyOverrides += "org.avaje.ebeanorm" % "avaje-ebeanorm" % "3.2.5"
```

I didn't even need the ebean.properties file after that.